# add a new column to spark dataframe from array list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add a new column to spark data frame as below:

val abc :Array[String] = ("a","b","c","d")

I am trying to add this Array[String] as new column to dataframe and trying to do sha2 on that new column

var words=abc.mkString("||")
source = source.withColumn("newcolumn", sha2(col(words), 256).cast(StringType))

It complied and the  runtime error i am getting as

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`a||b||c||d||e`' given input columns:

The expected output should be a dataframe with newcolum as column name and the value as varchar64 with sha2 of concatenate of Array of string with ||.

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **`lit(words)`** and caluculate `sha2(col,256)`

**`Example`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

var words=abc.mkString("||")

val source = source.withColumn("newcolumn",sha2(lit(words),256))
source.show()
//+----------------------------------------------------------------+
//|newcolumn                                                       |
//+----------------------------------------------------------------+
//|b51ff0f0a6aa9f36848b8fdc10ece7242698a4061e141c761b1ac9a08634c067|
//+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @SparkUser personal thanks are always welcome :) although upvoting and accepting the answer that helped you is even better for the StackOverflow users since they spend time and effort to answer them

Comment: Actually it's my bad. The question itself is wrong. I have val abc : is set of columns.I want to add this set of column values with || separator and sha2  as a newcolumn  in dataframe.                 I will do upvoting and accept the answer.

Comment: @SparkUser, Just posted answer for the new question.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61376746/7632695